# Symfony: Use querybuilder to build select options joining two tables

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

In Symfony I have a form with a Select option with the book titles of some authors, such as this:

```
->add('title', EntityType::class, [
            'class' => 'AppBundle:Title',
            'choice_label' => 'fullTitle',
            'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) {
                $queryBuilder = $er->createQueryBuilder('title');
                $queryBuilder
                    ->select('title')
                    ->innerJoin('title.author', 'author')
                    ->addOrderBy('author.name', 'ASC')
                    ->addOrderBy('title.title', 'ASC');

                return $queryBuilder;
            },
            'label' => 'fields.title.title'
        ])
```

I want to display the author name and the title name this way: "Author > Title". I managed to do so by using the "fullTitle" choice label and with this hack in the Title entity:

```
public function getFullTitle()
{
    return $this->getAuthor()->getSurname() . ',  ' . $this->getAuthor()->getName() . ' > ' . $this->getTitle();
}
```

But this is quite bad in many ways, specially for performance.
So I tried to build the "Author > Title" string in the query using CONCAT but it seems it can not be done with query builder.

I've checked the documentation and all the examples are about one single Entity, without joins.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to select both `title` as well as `author`, otherwise `author` will still be loaded via lazy loading. Adding `->addSelect('author')` should be enough.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to optimize data loading, you can use a partial request with needed informations in your query builder and use a closure to build label without modify the entity

```
    ->add('title', EntityType::class, [
        'class' => 'AppBundle:Title',
        'choice_label'  => function ($entity) {
             return $entity->getAuthor()->getSurname() . ',  ' .
                    $entity->getAuthor()->getName() . ' > ' . 
                    $entity->getTitle();
         },
        'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) {
            $queryBuilder = $er->createQueryBuilder('title');
            $queryBuilder
                ->select('partial title.{id, title}')
                ->addSelect('partial author.{id, surname, name}')
                ->innerJoin('title.author', 'author')
                ->addOrderBy('author.name', 'ASC')
                ->addOrderBy('title.title', 'ASC');

            return $queryBuilder;
        },
        'label' => 'fields.title.title'
    ])
```

I don't think `EntityType` can manage scalar result like `CONCAT` because object hydrator is used to get entities.

Best regards